# the use of "if we are to believe" and "if we were to believe"

Tags: subjunctives

Consider the following sentence. This is an exercise from a grammar book, the portion in bold is the answer to a blank.

> if **we are to** believe the media hype, the world should have ended
> several times over in the last decade.

why should we use "we are to believe", isn't "we were to believe' a better option here?

Comment: No: the difference is mainly one of formality, irrealis "were" being more formal than present tense   "are". Additionally, older speakers tend to prefer the former.

Comment: @BillJ: I disagree. I'd say *If we **are** to believe X* usually implies the speaker / writer ***is*** inclined to believe X, whereas *If we **were** to believe X* strongly implies he ***doesn't*** believe it. Obviously in the *specific* case here, that "usual" interpretation doesn't apply. (We know that because the world *didn't* end several times over the past decade! :)

Comment: To me, AmE, both usages sound disbelieving, though the "If we are to believe" sounds a touch more formal and haughty. Reason: Conditional believing suggests that it'd be a stretch to believe, inherently assuming that believing is rather easy.

Comment: I don't think the degree of modal remoteness plays much of a part in a remote conditional like this one. Generally, irrealis "were" is an untidy relic of an earlier system, and some speakers usually, if not always, use a present tense form (or the preterite where appropriate).